# Assign two values in scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to assign two values at once in scala? I mean code like:

```
var a: Int = 0
var b: Int = 0

(a, b) = methodReturningTupleOfInts()
```

Where of course methodReturningTupleOfInts returns `(Int, Int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that is possible with *values*.

Being able to do such things with ease is the selling point of functional languages.

```
def myMethod(i:Int) = (i+1, i+2)

@Test
def testit() {
    val (a,b) = myMethod(5)

    Assert.assertEquals(a, 6)
    Assert.assertEquals(b, 7)
}
```

Please note we used a **val** above. What happens here is actually a pattern match to extract components of a compound term. But such is not possible with *variables*. It is thus *not* possible to do several assignments to at once to *variables*.

Because, *changing values could have side effects*. That would cause a lot of complexities, since then the order of performing this match and assignments would be relevant. Thus, if you really need a variable, then you need to extract the components of the tuple explicitly and assign them one by one

```
def myMethod(i:Int) = (i+1, i+2)

var (a,b) = (2,3)

@Test
def testit() {
    Assert.assertEquals(a, 2)
    Assert.assertEquals(b, 3)

    val result = myMethod(5)
    a = result._1
    b = result._2

    Assert.assertEquals(a, 6)
    Assert.assertEquals(b, 7)
}
```

Note the compound initialisation of the tuple (a,b) works and is OK. But it is not allow to alter it with a compound assignment. `(a,b) = myMethod(5)` would not compile